# Problem installing orrosplanning package

Tags: ros, openrave

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I try to install package orrosplanning in ROS but I get this error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so.2.3: undefined reference to `cv::gpu::GpuMat::release()'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../feature0d_view] Error 1
```

I think is by opencv lib, obviously, but last week this didn't happen.

If someone knows something about this I appreciated answers.

Cheers,

Raúl

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29182/problem-installing-orrosplanning-package/) by [raul.perula](https://answers.ros.org/users/1826/raul.perula/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ask myself. I had opencv installed by repository and ROS version of opencv and there was a conflict choosing the path.

I uninstalled opencv from svn repository and now compile fine.

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [raul.perula](https://answers.ros.org/users/1826/raul.perula/) with karma: 71 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0